# Assembly storing float to memory

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips

I'm working on a mini-compiler. I want to store a float number to the memory, but I want to store it in the following way:

First, I want to reserve a space for 2 variables.

Then, I want to put number 2 in the first one (this will give me information later that I stored float in this location), and I want to put the actual float number in the second one.

I want to reserve a space for integer too, the first variable (the flag) is 4 for integer in my code.

I seem to get an error in some cases (not all cases). it says that I'm accessing unreadable place on the memory.
here's my code :

```
ori $a2,$0,2
ori $v0,$0,9
syscall
addi $sp,$sp,-8
sw  $v0,0($sp)
ori $t2,$0,1
sw  $t2,4($v0)
ori $t2,$0,4
sw  $t2,0($v0)
ori $a2,$0,2
ori $v0,$0,9
syscall
addi $sp,$sp,-8
sw  $v0,0($sp)
li.s    $f2,1.2
s.s $f2,4($v0)
ori $t2,$0,2
sw  $t2,0($v0)
```

In this code I'm first saving an integer (1) with flag 4.

Then, I'm saving a float (1.2) with flag 2.

This case gives an exception, in some other cases it doesn't give any exception, but the float number is rounded. Like if it was 2.5, then it's stored as 2.5000002.

Can any one help me with that?

Comment: This is how floats work in computers: they are *relative precision*. It isn't that it is 'rounded' - that is the *most accurate representation the (float) data type can manage*.

Comment: See this link https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf

Comment: thanks, but my problem is the exception thing. I just said the rounding thing to make sure I get it right.

Comment: can you help me with the exception thing, please? @user2864740

Comment: Syscall #9 expects number of bytes to allocate, not words. You only allocate 2 bytes and want to stuff 8 bytes into it.

Comment: I corrected it, but it still gives an error in the same place @Jester

Comment: Should we assume that you're using MIPS assembly?

Comment: yeah I'm sorry I forgot to write that I'm using MIPS32 assembly

Comment: `same place` ... where is that place? Which instruction? And what does your debugger say for the relevant addresses at that point?

Comment: it gives an exception at this instruction s.s $f2,4($v0), the debugger says that an exception occurred at this instruction. Bad address in data/ stack read.

Comment: And what's in `$v0` at that point? Did you fix the size for the second allocation too?

Comment: yes sure I fixed the second allocation too. $v0 has the value 10040008.

Comment: Duh, you are using `$a2` and not `$a0` as you should to pass the size ...

Comment: Thx a lot !! I have no idea how did I miss that. I'm building a compiler and I reached the code generation process. I missed it on one place, so the generated code had all the sizes passed to a2 instead of a0. Thx a lot again !!